# Shoutem Schema Design

Tags: shoutem

I have a question related to the data schema setup. For example, I want to create a list of objects, and in each object have another list object. So how should the schema look? And how should I set up the adminPages property in the extentions.js?

In addition, I want to access the user data login that created by Shoutem Cloud Server to add, edit, or remove the user.

Thank you all so much.

Answer (score 1):

I answered on the [Facebook community](https://www.facebook.com/groups/shoutem.community/permalink/338387566619577/?comment_id=338738876584446) group, but I figured I'd answer here as well.

Regarding the schema, keep in mind it's just a Shoutem flavored JSON schema. We do have a [reference](http://shoutem.github.io/docs/cloud/data-schemas) for it. Look into "Custom referenced schema - array" and "Custom referenced schema - Single object".

Regarding user management, currently we don't have an exposed API that developers could utilize to manage users in the way you described.